# Find the number of times each digit appears?

Tags: c

> Write a C function count digits(int num); where num is a positive integer. The function counts how many times each of the digits 0..9 appears in num, and prints the results (each on a new line.) Eg:

```
The digit 0 appeared 0 time(s) in 347213
    The digit 1 appeared 1 time(s) in 347213
.....
```

> **Use iteration**

```
int count_digits(int num){

int counter = 0;
int nDigits = floor(log10(abs(num))) + 1;

for(int i=0; i < nDigits; i++){
// How do I get each char of the integer?


}

}
```

The main issue I am having is analyzing each char. Do I use `getchar()`?

Comment: Since `getchar()` reads from `stdin` and you already have the `num` for which you desire digit counts, I'm going to go ahead and say `getchar()` is pointless here. This is an exercise in division and modulo operations, maintaining a counter array of ten elements.

Answer (score 2):

```
void count_digits(int num) {
    int i, arr[10] = {0}, e = num;

    if (num == 0) arr[0]++;
    else if (num < 0) num *= (-1);

    while (num > 0) {
        arr[num % 10]++;
        num /= 10;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("%d appears %d times in %d\n", i, arr[i], e);
    } 
}
```

This is a simple code for this purpose.

1. I used `num > 0` as the condition for stopping the loop execution.
2. I took the remainder of the `num` when divided by 10 `num % 10` and incremented the count value in the array corresponding to this remainder(`arr[num % 10]++`).
3. I then divided `num` by `10`. The loop then repeats until the condition is un-satisfied.
4. Then I just printed the values.

Edit:  `arr[10] = {0}` initializes the array `arr` of size `10` with `0`s.

Edit 2: `if(num == 0) arr[0]++`. This line checks whether the number input is 0 and increments the count in the array `arr` if it is equal to `0`

Edit 3: As per, @chux's suggestion, I have made necessary changes so that the function even handles negative numbers.

Comment: One optimization: You can do `int arr[10] = {0};` and remove the first `for` loop.

Comment: Yes, @MayurK! :-)

Comment: Note: should `num < 0`, then `arr[num % 10]++;` is a problem.  Also `count_digits(0)` prints nothing.

Comment: "Why should num < 0 cause a problem?" --> `count_digits(-42)` will print nothing rather than 1 for 4 and 1 for 2 given OP's title goal of "Find the number of times each digit appears?".  True, OP's post mentions "num is a positive integer." so the the correct function with negative values is implementation dependent and commenting this as a problem is an overstatement.

Comment: @chux, I think you are right. I have made edits so that it works even for negative numbers.

Comment: Edit handles negative numbers correctly except `count_digits(INT_MIN)`, Case outside OP goals though.

Comment: @chux, ohh yeah!

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of way to determine the frequency of the individual digits in a number. Many times it is just as easy to handle the number in *sting* format as opposed to a number it self. The approach to determining frequency is identical in each case, so match your routine to the type of data you are dealing with.

The short example below, simply loops using `mod` to extract the digits from any number passed to the `ndigits()` function. Since you are only concerned with the frequency of the digits, there is no reordering of the separated numbers as would be required in a typical *conversion* process. You pass your zero-initialized frequency array as a parameter to the function, and within the function, you simply update the element that corresponds to whatever digit is encountered. On return, the array contains the per-digit frequency for each digit in the number passed as 'n':

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>  /* for atoi */

#define NDIG 10   /* array size to hold frequency of digits (0-9) */

int ndigits (int n, int *a);

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    int a[NDIG] = {0};        /* initialize freq array to all 0 */
    int n = argc > 1 ? atoi (argv[1]) : 347213,   /* set number */
        nd = ndigits (n, a);   /* get number of digits/set freq */

    printf (" the frequency of digits in '%d' (%d digits):\n\n", n, nd);
    printf (" digits | frequency\n--------+---------\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < NDIG; i++)  /* output elements of freq array */
        printf (" %6d | %2d\n", i, a[i]);

    return 0;
}

/* record the frequency of digits in 'n' in array 'a' */
int ndigits (int n, int *a)
{
    int d = 0;
    for (; n; n /= 10, d++)
        a[n % 10]++;

    return d;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/freq_digits
 the frequency of digits in '347213' (6 digits):

 digits | frequency
--------+---------
      0 |  0
      1 |  1
      2 |  1
      3 |  2
      4 |  1
      5 |  0
      6 |  0
      7 |  1
      8 |  0
      9 |  0
```

Look it over and let me know if you have any additional questions.

Comment: Note code is UB with a negative `n`, but then OP did say "where num is a positive integer".

Comment: Ah, yes, to cover the negative input case here, tucking an `if (n < 0) n = -n;` after the declaration of `d` would catch the unexpected negative input case.

Comment: ... aside from that pesky `m = INT_MIN`

Comment: Yes, that is pesky. In that case you would have to move the conditional within the loop and save and test the result of `n % 10` before incrementing the array element. (grumble signed numbers...)

Comment: ,,, or with c99 `if (if (n > 0) n = -n; do { a[-(n % 10)]++; } while (n /= 10);` and embrace the [negative](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Dark_side_of_the_Force/Legends) side.

Comment: Those are both keepers. What a different place the world wold be if Anakin hadn't been turned... I kinda like `if (n < 0) n = -n; for (; n; n /= 10, d++) a[n % 10]++;` but technically, since `a[n % 10]++` will be evaluated at least once, the `do ...` form is correct from the micro-optimization standpoint.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
int sprintf(char * restrict str, const char * restrict format, ...);
```

With this function you can put your integer into a string and after you can compare with the table ascii each character `tab[i] = '1'`...

Answer (score 0):

Using `% 10` is a simple way to exact one decimal digit at a time from `int num`.

`log10(abs(num))` has trouble with some non-positive numbers 0 and perhaps `INT_MIN`.  It also has trouble should the precision of `int` exceed the precision of `double`.  This precision issue is not common but does occur on select 64-bit machines.  IAC, no *need* for `double` and a good solution exist with `int` math.

`some_int % 10` results in a value [-9 ... 9], so code uses `abs()`.

```
// A solution that handles the entire range of `int` including 0 and INT_MIN
void count_digits(int num) {
  int x = num;
  int digit_count[10] = { 0 };

  // use a do loop to insure at least 1 pass - important for num == 0
  do {
    int digit = x % 10;
    digit_count[abs(digit)]++;
    x /= 10;
  } while (x);

  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    // As desired, eliminate the "if" test to always display 10 lines.
    if (digit_count[i]) {
      printf("The digit %d appeared %d time(s) in %d\n", i, digit_count[i], num);
    }
  }
}
```

Sample usage

```
#include <limits.h>
int main(void) {
  count_digits(347213);
  count_digits(0);
  count_digits(INT_MIN);
  return 0;
}

The digit 1 appeared 1 time(s) in 347213
The digit 2 appeared 1 time(s) in 347213
The digit 3 appeared 2 time(s) in 347213
The digit 4 appeared 1 time(s) in 347213
The digit 7 appeared 1 time(s) in 347213
The digit 0 appeared 1 time(s) in 0
The digit 1 appeared 1 time(s) in -2147483648
The digit 2 appeared 1 time(s) in -2147483648
The digit 3 appeared 1 time(s) in -2147483648
The digit 4 appeared 3 time(s) in -2147483648
The digit 6 appeared 1 time(s) in -2147483648
The digit 7 appeared 1 time(s) in -2147483648
The digit 8 appeared 2 time(s) in -2147483648
```